# The program give "segmentation fault" when is run, but when i do completely the same in debugger it works just fine

Tags: c, cs50

So i am making a program for caesar code. Here's the code

```
 int main(int argc,  string argv[])
 {
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("The usage of the program is ./caesar + number");
    return 1;
}
else
if (isdigit(argv[1])==0)
{
    printf("The usage of the program is ./caesar + number");
    return 1;
}
else
{

int k = atoi(argv[1]);

string text=get_string("write your text here: ");
int l=strlen(text);
for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
    if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')
    {
    text[i] = (((text[i]+k-97))%26)+97;}
    
    else if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')
    {
                text[i] = (((text[i]+k-65))%26)+65;
    }
    
}
for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
printf("%c", text[i]);
}
 }

 }`
```

When i run it, it gives me "segmentation fault". But if i do completely the same actions but it debugger mode from cs50, it works just fine. But nothing in code changes. I tried different inputs but it doesn't matter. everything is the same. How is it possible and how can i fix it? As debbuger cannot show me where is the problem, i just can suppose that the thing is in my checking whether is it digit. Why? Cause this function is new to me, I've never used it, and maybe i use it in the wrong way

Comment: Your title is a very common description of a program invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: argv[1] is a string, isdigit() takes a char as parameter. So, you need at least do: if isdigit(argv[1][0]). As you tagged you question with "c language", the entry point of the program shoud be C compliant : int main(int argc, char *argv[]). Unless string is a typedef of "char *" ?

Comment: Are you sure that get_string() put a terminating '\0' at the end of text ? I suppose that get_string() is doing some kind of dynamic allocation. If there is no terminating '\0' in the string, strlen() may crash.

Comment: @RachidK., yes, in CS50 `string` is essentially a typedef of `char*`. A terrible beginner libray BTW.

Comment: `isdigit(argv[1])` is bad because `argv[1]` is a *pointer*, not a character.

Comment: @RachidK. and yes `get_string` is an implementation of the same library which parses a string from stdin, and the implementation, unless tampered with, does work correctly. The `isdigit` issue is probably the problem here.

Comment: The code gets more magic-number as it goes: it begins with `isdigit()` but ignores the existence of `islower()` and `isupper()` finally using hard coded ASCII values like `97` directly instead of `'a'`.

Comment: For the error messages, it is better to use the stderr stream. So, instead of printf(), call fprintf(stderr, "..."). Moreover, put an '\n' at the end of the message to terminate the displayed line on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check every character of argv[1]. That is the usage of isdigit in the documentation.

For more information, go to https://manual.cs50.io/3/isdigit